# Paypal express checkout - buyer details

Tags: php, paypal

so I need to ask a question, I need to setup a simple paypal express checkout system, that one can allow users to change currencies, and two can then update the page with the updated currencies.

Then I need a way for me to get the order information. As I will be selling website templates so I need a way for me to get their email address, so I can then email them with the link to the template file download.

So my question is what data do I get if I set up an express checkout system. And what code do I need, Do i need to create a database to get the returned data back from paypal? Or do I just get an email or can i see that when i log into my paypal account and check orders and see their details that way, but the main important detail i need is their email address?

Can I also say that this is the first time I have looked into express shopping carts. So I am a complete novice in this field, So I will struggle with the coding aspect. But I think it is the route I need to go down.

Also I want to make it all in php as well. But also I don't want to use ready made systems. I just need the back-end code so that I can then just implement it into my current design. Not sure if paypal give you the code when you click the express shopping cart option in All tool section. I did notice though it redirects to a page that lists many partner sites. I couldn't find anywhere for any implementation advice or tips or code.

EDIT: Also I know I will also need to use either IPN or PDT but the documentation I read is highly confusing and just is making me unsure if I can even set a system up. I also read that you should implement both systems, but I also read that that had a risk of doing the payment twice. So yeah i am kinda a bit unsure how to even go about implementing a system I need.

Thanks in advance.